# Caesar Cipher code issue with random keys and spaces

Tags: python

```
def message():
    answer = input('Welcome to the Caesar Cipher! What do you want to encrypt?')
    key = input('Enter the key number that you want to encrypt with. (1 - 25)')
    return answer, int(key)


def getMessage(answer, key):
    lengthList = []
    leng = 0
    while leng < len(answer):
        lengthList.append(chr(ord(answer[leng]) + key))
        leng += 1
    print("By the way, random keys are spaces.")
    print("".join(lengthList))


answer, key = message()
getMessage(answer, key)
```

This is my Caesar Cipher Encryption Only code and my problem is that sometimes when I enter a message, some letters turn into different signs that are not letters. How do I make the printed message only include keys? I also need help that if there are spaces, it also turns into a different sign. How do you also make the spaces remain spaces?

Comment: see this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472494/implementing-the-ceaser-cipher-function-through-input-in-python/53472605#53472605

Comment: It still doesn't meet my question of staying in the alphabet.

Comment: Without seeing an example, I'm guessing the leaving the alphabet problem is what happens if you have, for example, the character 'Z' and `key=1` then the ciphered version of this character is '[', so you'll need to handle "wrapping" around. That point is addressed in the linked question/answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing the Ceaser Cipher function through input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472494/implementing-the-ceaser-cipher-function-through-input-in-python)